# Application crashes and transactions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a application that handles money transfers.

```
try {
    transaction.Commit();
}  catch {
    transaction.Rollback();
}
```

Now what happens, if it turns out that the Commit has to be canceled, and for some reason the program crashes before the cancel or rollback is handled?
How can I program my application so that it will be robust against program crashes.

**EDIT:**
What if I don't have an SQL backend, and the transaction is something I myself have implemented?

Comment: your "what if" invalidates everything... if you don't have a database and you implemented an object called carrot ( or transaction, is unclear the same to us ), you should specify way more what your carrot class does, what inherits and how it's implemented !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is fine (even if very minimalist with no real example in it...)

you can imagine that once you call `var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();`

if you do not call commit the transaction will not get committed so the catch will roll it back.

if for any reason a crash prevents execution of the catch block auto rollback will be applied by the SQL engine.

Answer (score 3):

Data persistence in Db would be achieved only **after** the Commit is successfull. So if your Commit fails in any position, the data would not be written to db.